# The use of "the customer"

Tags: grammar

I read somewhere on the internet that when you use nouns to make general statements, there are two patterns that have the same meaning:

1. Use the + singular noun
2. Use a plural or non-count noun with no article.

For example:

(1)**The computer** has brought about huge changes in education. (**“Computers have...”** is also correct)

(2)**The hybrid class** is more effective than the 100% online class. (**“hybrid classes are...”** is also correct)

(3) **The dog** is a friendly animal. (**“dogs are...”** is also correct)

I saw a job description on the internet, it says:

A Customer Experience Specialist is expected to champion customer satisfaction by demonstrating the highest level of professionalism, listening and engaging with **the customer.**

I have 2 opinions, but I don't know which one is correct, The writer uses **“the customer”** because:

He/she wants to imply: A Customer Experience Specialist is expected to champion customer …. **the customer** *(While they are working with a customer).*

Or

The use **“the customer”** here to mean customers in general as in sentences (1)(2)(3).

Could you  help me clarify?

Comment: It's simple,here "the" is used to specify the **customer=Every customer ( that you want to satisfy).**

Comment: The with a singular noun is **more formal** than the plural form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *the customer* means customers in general exactly as in your other examples.